# Scripts and styles are not not working in claims based identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, claims

I am an ASP.Net MVC application that uses claims based identity. I created a security token service (STS) for authentication. My MVC application is hosted on IIS default website. My application is working perfectly. But scripts are not working. Currently I have disabled anonymous authentication (which is a the requirement). Thank you.

Error Message:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the solution.

For claims based identity, We have to configure on webconfig as follows:

```
<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"  preCondition="integratedMode" />
      <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
```

It will work.

Thank you all.............

Comment: do you know if this is also a requirement for MVC5 which appears to used a claims based model.

Comment: that web.config section you specified, it isn't in my web.config  from a vs2013 preview MVC5  template. So the question is, If i am using the new claims based model in MVC5 should i have the web.config modules section you specified? and or, i assume windows forms authentication should be disabled on the website.

Comment: No on the MVC5 it will not be there. After adding identity and access procedure it will create in your web config.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e

Comment: If it helps anyone else, note the `preCondition="integratedMode"` on the end of each <add /> element. This was set to `preCondition="managedHandler"` in my project. After changing to "integratedMode" it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should allow access to scripts folder to all requests, add this to web.config. Allow access to CSS folder also in the same way.

```
<location path="Scripts">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I have added this code in webconfig file. But not working. In IIS I have disabled anonymous authentication.

Comment: Also My script path is  http://localhost/Framework/dept/cdadepst.js....... Then how can I add the location path... Can you give me a solution?

Comment: Make sure the path you given is correct. You need to specify only relative path.

Comment: relative path means... <location path="Framework/dept"> is it...?

Comment: I am using claims based identity is this issue with this identity privider?

Comment: but it is not working even now. I have tested with all aspects of relative path. but not working now. But on the iis i havedisabled aonymous authentication. its my requirement also